# How to rasterize a specific angle of circle, MIDPOINT

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, geometry

I'm facing a problem. I'm trying to rasterize just part of circle using midpoint algorithm. The part is entered by startAngle, endAngle.

With help of google I did this:

```
public RasterImage<PixelType> rasterizeCircleSector(RasterImage<PixelType> img,
                                                    double centerX, double centerY,
                                                    double x, double y,
                                                    int startAngle, int endAngle,
                                                    PixelType value){

    RasterImage<PixelType> result = img;

    int angle = (int)toDegrees(atan2(y, x));

    if(x<y) {
        if (90 - angle >= startAngle && 90 - angle <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX - y), (int) (centerY - x), value);
        }
        if (angle >= startAngle && angle <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX - x), (int) (centerY - y), value);
        }
        if (180 - angle >= startAngle && 180 - angle <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX + x), (int) (centerY - y), value);
        }
        if (angle + 90 >= startAngle && angle + 90 <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX + y), (int) (centerY - x), value);
        }
        if (270 - angle >= startAngle && 270 - angle <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX + y), (int) (centerY + x), value);
        }
        if (angle + 180 >= startAngle && angle + 180 <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX + x), (int) (centerY + y), value);
        }
        if (360 - angle >= startAngle && 360 - angle <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX - x), (int) (centerY + y), value);
        }
        if (angle + 270 >= startAngle && angle + 270 <= endAngle) {
            result.withPixel((int) (centerX - y), (int) (centerY + x), value);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Angles work fine, but the problem is that, I do not know how to rasterize every point on circle (this code rasterize just 8 points)

Calling function:

```
    rasterImage = linerCircle.rasterizeCircleSector(rasterImage,200,200,
            15, 30,
            1, 200,
            0xf0f0f0);
```

and the result is:

[image]

Can anybody help me? or is this method completely wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Emm... You mentioned midpoint algorithm - it updates x and y in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Midpoint (and Bresenham) algorithm usually fill one octant (sometimes one quadrant) of  circle, mirroring points to fill other octants.

At first you need to determine - what octant start and end angles belong to, and what octants are filled completely (if exist).

Then get x/y limits for starting and ending angles.

Then apply midpoint algorithm, omitting points that lie out of calculated x/y limits and filling needed parts of the circle.